# Google Prediction Api : Update on regression model

Tags: google-prediction

I have created a regression model and wanted to update some data using Predicion.[update](https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs/reference/v1.6/trainedmodels/update) api for machine learning purpose.

The java api doc for [update](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/prediction/v1.6/java/latest/) class "setOutput function" is not very clear for me. It says output value as "regression or class label". Does that mean that for regression model, I should call the setOutPut("regression")?.

Also, how can I verify if my update is successful?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

prediction.trainedmodels.get,check the modelInfo/numberInstances,is the number add 1?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the output value of your training instance.

for example if you have a movie rating instance like:

`Rating  Genre   Title
   10    Crime   Godfather`

The output should be 10 and the rest should go in the csvInstance.